What is the “data file browser” that appears in the film “Segreto di stato” (1995)?
From the movie "Segreto di stato" (1995) at minute 01:29


Looks like mere Hollywood prop graphics?

Probably, but can also be not

Are there any more images, or a video clip?

No sorry, it appear this image for a few seconds.

I've just watched the film (I'm studying Italian and this is perfect for my current skills).
This file browser does not exist as-is, it has clearly been made up for the film (although it might have been inspired by some Amiga/AtariST/MSX2 stuff). There are some reasons that clearly point to this:

Resolution. The picture is using a 320x200 mode on a PC from 1995. We're talking an era where Windows already allowed desktop UI in a modern sense (as we understand it today).
Intentionally readable buttons: having such a low resolution, as a developer, who would waste so many pixels using "STAMPA" and "SFOGLIA" buttons? They have been designed so the audience can read them easily while watching the film.
That floppy disk icon does not make any sense other than showing the audience those files come from the floppy disk the actors just got. In a real file browser, you would have a disk selection tool (to tell the system what drive you want to browse).
Text output is slow, showing a cursor and printing char by char (as if it was an old terminal or a matrix printer). Why would a graphic file browser show the names this way? The only reason is that it's just a cinematic effect, not an actual file browser.

EDIT: I add another screenshot that better shows this aspects


Ottimo, dettagliato e spiegato bene :)
